# Determine if two sequences using the listed formula contains an identical element...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two sequences, that use the following formula to construct:

(n·i)-i^2 (where n is any number, and i is the index of the element in the constructed sequence), such as:

n = 20 would result in:
19, 36, 51, 64, 75, 84, 91, 96, 99, ...

n = 22 would result in:
21, 40, 57, 72, 85, 96, 105, ...

I need a formula that, when used, would determine that both of these sequences (using the above provided formula) contain a matching identical element (which would be 96, in this case).

I hope I made sense, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're starting with two integers $m$ and $n$, say $m = 22$ and $n = 20$ in your example, and you're looking for positive integers $i, j$ such that
$$mi - i^2 = nj - j^2.$$
My suggestion: rewrite this equation as
$$m^2 - n^2 = (2i - m)^2 - (2j - n)^2.$$
You now need to express $m^2 - n^2$ as the difference of two squares which have the same parity as $m$ and $n$ respectively. There are always the trivial solutions
$$2i - m = \pm m,\quad 2j - n = \pm n$$
which lead to $i = 0$ or $m$, $j = 0$ or $n$, corresponding to the fact that 0 occurs in all of your sequences. In the example, the only other possibility is $84 = 10^2 - 4^2$.
This gives $i = 16$ or $6$, $j = 12$ or $8$, corresponding to the fact that 96 occurs twice in each sequence. Hope this is some help.

Comment: Thank you, Michael... appreciate the detailed reply.  I completely understand it, and it's what I was looking for.